# react-notification-system on various components

Tags: reactjs

I am learning to use [igorprado's react-notification-system](https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system).

I followed the docs and have  set up on the top level HTML element and the other set up on my main router file.

Main.jsx

```
import NotificationSystem from 'react-notification-system';
this.state = { _notificationSystem: null };
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ _notificationSystem: this.refs.notificationSystem });
}

handleNotificationClick(title, message, level, position){
    this.state._notificationSystem.addNotification({
        title: title,
        message: message,
        level: level,
        position: position,
        autoDismiss: 15
    });
}
...
render(){
    return(
        <prop.component
            notification={this.handleNotificationClick}
        />
    )
}
```

Table.jsx

```
<Button 
    onClick={this.deleteRows} 
    onClick={()=>this.props.notification("Update", "Row Deleted", "info", "tr")}
</Button>
```

Now:

- Button is working with onClick event separately.

Questions:

- How to have multiple onClick events?
- Can I have addNotification() in my Table.jsx?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you facing issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to run multiple onClick events.

a). Seperate method calling:- In this method, you can call more then one events that you want to call in action by enclosing them in parent function and calling that parent method in onClick event. Like this:

```
parentMethod(event){
  deleteRows();
  this.props.notification("Update", "Row Deleted", "info", "tr");
}

<Button 
    onClick={this.parentMethod} 
</Button>
```

b). Inline Method:- In this method , you don't have to use parent function to call multiple functions. Here you just add them in same onClick event side by side seperated by semi-colon. Like this:

```
<Button href="#" onClick={(event) => { deleteRows();  this.props.notification("Update", "Row Deleted", "info", "tr");}}></Button>
```

Now regarding addnotification() method, you should have read the document and as it says that "addnotification()". This displays the notification based on the object you passed.

Hope it helps